# Python Datetime Timezone Shift

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

I have a time string disseminated from a MQTT broker that I would like to read and convert from its native timezone (U.S. Central Time) to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). I am currently using Python 3.8.5 in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, with the machine timezone set to UTC.

The time string is as follows: **1636039288.815212**

To work with this time in Python, I am using a combination of the datetime and pytz libraries. My current core of code is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

input = 1636039288.815212
srctime = datetime.fromtimestamp(input, tz=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
```

After running this chunk, I receive the following undesired time output:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 4, 10, 21, 28, 815212, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
```

It appears that despite explicitly defining 'US/Central' inside the initial timestamp conversion, 5 hours were subsequently subtracted the initial time provided.

What additional steps/alterations can I make to ensure that the initial time provided is unchanged, defined as US/Central, and that I can subsequently change to UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `fromtimestamp` assumes that your input is [UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which should refer to 1970-01-01 UTC, not some arbitrary time zone. If you encounter such a thing nevertheless (another epoch time zone), you'll need to set UTC and then `replace` the tzinfo:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz # pip install python-dateutil

ts = 1636039288.815212

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=tz.UTC).replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz("US/Central"))

print(dt)
# 2021-11-04 16:21:28.815212-05:00

# or in UTC:
print(dt.astimezone(tz.UTC))
# 2021-11-04 20:21:28.815212+00:00
```

Note that I'm using `dateutil` here so that the replace operation is safe. Don't do that with pytz (you must use `localize` there). Once you upgrade to Python 3.9 or higher, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) instead, so you only need the standard library.

Comment: Excellent explanation, makes sense why the time was off given the assumption is UNIX and Pytz was utilized without localize (that should have tipped me off faster). I am accepting your answer, +1 for the heads up on zoneinfo as well in Python 3.9.